# How to make XSLT xsl:if work

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to make this (xml 1.0) code work . I am new to this and already exhausted myself in
trying different ways. Does someone know my mistake?

```
<xsl:for-each select="News/Sport">

  <xsl:if test="local-name()='Basketball'">
    <p>
      <xsl:text>Basketball Sport</xsl:text>
    </p>
    <xsl:value-of select="News/Sport/Basketball/Phrases/Phrase"/>
  </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
```

When I transform it into an HTML file the content doesn't show up. When I remove the `xsl:for each` and the `xsl:if statements` the content is successfully presented. I only wish that the content is first checked (if it is available in the XML file) and if yes, that it is taken from the XML content.

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT:

This is my XML code

```
<News>
  <Sport>
    <Basketball>
      <Phrases>
        <Phrase>Zach Randolph recovered the opening tipoff in Game 1 of the Western Conference Finals, and he didn’t touch the ball again until the possession following the Grizzlies’ first timeout.
        </Phrase>
        <Phrases>
    </Basketball>
  </Sport>
</News>
```

**EDIT2:**

Could you tell me why I cannot apply a template inside this below function? Only the text works now:(

```
<xsl:for-each select="News/Sport[Basketball]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="News/Sport/*" />
</xsl:for-each>

  <xsl:template match="Basketball">
    <p>
      <xsl:text>Basketball Sport</xsl:text>
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Phrases/Phrase"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Without seeing the whole code, `local-name()='Basketball'`, I think you might need to use `==` double equals so you're doing a comparison and not re-assigning the value 'Basketball' to the function result. I would have to see more of the code to see the problem I think.

Thanks!

Comment: This is XSLT, not Java or C++. The comparison 'equals' operator is `=`

Comment: Without seeing your input XML nobody can tell you why your stylesheet isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="News/Sport">

    <xsl:if test="local-name()='Basketball'">
```

In this `if` test, the context node is a `Sport` element, so `local-name()` will always be `Sport` and will never equal Basketball.

> I only wish that the content is first checked (if it is available in the XML file) and if yes, that it is taken from the XML content.

The usual way to handle this sort of thing in XSLT is to define *templates* matching the various nodes that might be present and then applying templates to all the nodes that are actually found.  If there are no nodes of a particular type then the corresponding template will not fire

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <!-- apply templates that match all elements inside Sport, which may
             be Basketball, Football, etc. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="News/Sport/*" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- when we find a Basketball element ... -->
  <xsl:template match="Basketball">
    <p>
      <xsl:text>Basketball Sport</xsl:text>
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Phrases/Phrase"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- when we find a Football element ... -->
  <xsl:template match="Football">
    <p>
      <xsl:text>Football Sport</xsl:text>
    </p>
    <!-- whatever you need to do for Football elements -->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Phrase">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way you don't need any explicit `for-each` or `if`, the template matching logic handles it all for you.

Comment: got it work, thx a lot guys! I am trying to combine both suggestions and tried to execute a new template, but it somehow doesn't work. Could you have a look at the new code I posted above?

Comment: @HunaWanst the `apply-templates` would be _instead of_ the `for-each`, not inside it.  As @Borodin pointed out a `for-each` changes the context node, so essentially you're now trying to apply templates to `/News/Sport/News/Sport/*`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the idea of a *context node*. Within a `xsl:for-each`, everything you refer to is about or relative to the selected nodes. So, for instance, within `<xsl:for-each select="News/Sport">`, the context node is the `Sport` elements, and a test like `<xsl:if test="local-name()='Basketball'">` is always going to be *false* because the local name is always `Sport`.

It looks like you want just `<xsl:if test="Basketball">` which tests whether there are any `Basketball` child nodes of the current `Sport` node.

The same thing applies to `<xsl:value-of select="News/Sport/Basketball/Phrases/Phrase"/>`. Because everything is relative to the `Sport` node, XSLT is looking for `News/Sport/Basketball/Phrases/Phrase` *within the `Sport` element*, which never exists.

In addition, you can just put text in literally: there is no need for an `xsl:text` element here, so your code should look like

```
<xsl:for-each select="News/Sport">
  <xsl:if test="Basketball">
    <p>Basketball Sport</p>
    <xsl:value-of select="Basketball/Phrases/Phrase"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can refine this further by adding a *predicate* to the `for-each` selection, so that it matches only `Sport` elements with a `Basketball` child. Like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="News/Sport[Basketball]">
  <p>Basketball Sport</p>
  <xsl:value-of select="Basketball/Phrases/Phrase"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```